# Cannot understand "contradiction" in Robert Martin's ISP article

Tags: c++, solid-principles, vtable, interface-segregation-principle

I read the Robert Martin's article about the Interface Segregation Principle [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgOTViYjJhYzMtMzYxMC00MzFjLWJjMzYtOGJiMDc5N2JkYmJi/view). At the end of the article, when solving a problem with ATM UI architecture he stated:

> Consider also that each different transaction that the ATM can perform is encasulated as a derivative of the class Transaction. Thus we might have classes such as `DepositTransaction`, `WithdrawlTransaction`, `TransferTransaction`, etc. Each of these objects issues message to the `UI`. For example, the `DepositTransaction` object calls the `RequestDepositAmount` member function of the `UI` class. Whereas the `TransferTransaction` object calls the `RequestTransferAmount` member function of `UI`. This corresponds to the diagram in Figure 5.
>
> Notice that this is precicely the situation that the ISP tells us to avoid. Each of the transactions is using a portion of the `UI` that no other object uses. This creates the possibility that changes to one of the derivatives of `Transaction` will force coresponding change to the `UI`, thereby affecting all the other derivatives of Transaction, and every other class that depends upon the `UI` interface.

So we have the following situation: if one of `Transaction`'s derivatives is changed, then `UI` is changed **and any other class that uses `UI`** is changed too.

Then that problem is being solved by the following changes:

> This unfortunate coupling can be avoided by segregating the UI
>   interface into induvidual abstract base classes such as `DepositUI`,
>   `WithdrawUI` and `TransferUI`. These abstract base classes can then be
>   multiply inherited into the final `UI` abstract class. Figure6 and
>   Listing 6 show this model.

But next Robert Martin states that:

> It is true that, whenever a new derivative of the Transaction class is
>   created, a coresponding base class for the abstract UI class will be
>   needed. Thus the UI class and all its derivatives must change.
>   However, these classes are not widely used. Indeed, they are probably
>   only used by main, or whatever process boots the system and creates
>   the concrete UI instance. So the impact of adding new UI base classes
>   is contained.

And that's the question: how is it possible that `UI`'s changed but no other classes are changed too? After all, if some kind of `TransactionX` uses `XUI` and `XUI` is superclass of `UI` and `UI` is changed (because of some `ZUI`), then (as far as i'm concerned) compiler needs to recompile all the classes that use `XUI` too, because vtable (in terms of C++) or maybe some function base addresses have been changed by change of `UI`. Could someone make it clean for me?

Answer (score 0):

> if some kind of TransactionX uses XUI and XUI is superclass of UI and UI is changed, then (as far as i'm concerned) compiler needs to recompile all the classes that use XUI too

Yes but in this case, only `TransactionX` depends on `XUI`. All other `TransactionY` and `YUI` are not impacted and do not need to be recompiled.

> because vtable (in terms of C++) or maybe some function base addresses have been changed by change of UI.

You would recompile `main` (or `ui_globals.cc` in the text) which is where the address to the `X/Y/Z UI` interfaces are obtained to be passed to the `Transaction X/Y/Z` instances.